# Newer show activity for ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Tags: android, speech

I have this code:

```
/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and i'm doing call:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });
```

but i never seen activity with voice recording. Immediately there is a call:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mAdapter.addTag(result.get(0));
                //txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

with resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCEL

I have permission to Internet.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the toast display "speech not supported"? Do you have the permission :     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> ?

Comment: i found the problem, it was android:launchMode="singleInstance" in activity :(